# MatToolTip position is undefined or invalid

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Using this simple code here I keep getting a Tooltip position "undefined" is not a valid message

```
  <mat-form-field 

    matTooltip="Testing tooltips"
    [matTooltipPosition]='right'
    #tooltip="matTooltip">
           <input matInput [value]="Testing"/>
    </mat-form-field>
```

My app_module.ts has

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
```

I am using Angular 7.2. Is there something else that I need in order to get the tooltip position to work?

If I remove the matTooltipPosition then the tooltip shows fine but it's not in the place that I want it

Comment: Try adding it to input

Comment: I tried now I get "FlexibleConnectedPositionStrategy: At least one position is required."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the [] bracket

```
<mat-form-field 

    matTooltip="Testing tooltips"
    matTooltipPosition='right'
    #tooltip="matTooltip">
           <input matInput [value]="Testing"/>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[matTooltipPosition]='right'
```

This means we are doing Property Binding by which we are searching for this value('right') in the **.ts** file and as the value is not in the **.ts** file we are getting the error as **invalid**

By removing the **square brackets []** we are giving the value **'right'** directly through HTML file

```
<mat-form-field 
    matTooltip="Testing tooltips"
    matTooltipPosition='right'
    #tooltip="matTooltip">
  <input matInput [value]="Testing"/>
</mat-form-field>
```